# How to make custom item in minecraft bukkit [plugin]

Tags: plugins, bukkit

I just started making my first bukkit plugin. I wanted to make eggs that explode when they hit the ground, and I successfully made this. But now I want to have normal eggs and eggs that explode when they hit the ground. How can I create this?
I tried naming them differently, but entities don't have item names. How can I detect which thrown egg was is an egg that should explode and which is a normal egg?

If anything wasn't clear enough please ask me to explain it better, Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already?

Comment: You can set a UUID to the entity and retrieve it via getUUID() [Javadocs](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Entity.html#getUniqueId--)

Comment: An egg is also Metadatable, so you can add metadata to it, [Bukkit Forums](https://bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-metadata-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it.276338/)

Answer (score 3):

You can have an `EventHandler` for when a player throws the `Egg` you want, and add some MetaData to it:

```
@EventHandler
public void onProjectileLaunch(ProjectileLaunchEvent e){
    Projectile projectile = e.getEntity();
    if (//This projectile should be an explosive egg) {
        projectile.setMetadata("explosiveegg", new FixedMetadataValue(plugin, "explosiveegg";
    }
}
```

Then recover your Metadata whenever the `Egg` hits an `Entity` or the Floor and check if it's Metadata is "explosiveegg"

```
if (projectile.hasMetadata("explosiveegg")) //Explode
```